# How much is intentionality relevant to specific crime(s) in the US?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech

Let's say, person A who is not fluent in English, calls somebody else (B) by a derogatory or racist name or names, which might generally fall under some law restricting such speech (eg. hate speech) and gets sued for that.

Does it matter from legal perspective, if it can be proved that A either doesn't happen to know that this word is commonly understood as derogatory, or he was explicitly mislead by somebody else that it was a normal everyday word without any negative connotations, therefore, it can be proved that A didn't *mean* any harm to B by his speech?

Comment: Fortunately, the U.S. Supreme Court has repeatedly ruled that hate speech is legally protected free speech under the First Amendment . see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburg_v._Ohio for example

Answer (score 3):

In the US, there are no (and can be no) laws against hate speech. You also cannot sue a person for using an ethnic or similar epithet. A false accusation, however, might be grounds for a defamation lawsuit. Word connotations do not matter, what matters is the denotation, for example calling someone a "rapist" denotes a specific criminal act.

Even calling someone a rapist isn't necessarily defamatory, since hyperbole abounds especially on the internet, so in order to actually be defamation, the statement would have to be understood as a particular accusation (a form of unlawful sexual assault). A defamatory statement has to be made with reckless disregard for the truth of a statement, which is not the case in the situation you describe (perhaps the person correctly said that so-and-so is a therapist, but was ineffective in their use of English).

Comment: Note that while hate speech, as protected speech, cannot inherently be a crime, it can be used as evidence in support of a crime, such as assault, or a sentencing enhancement.

Comment: This question seems to be about a civil action rather than a crime, and while "hate speech" in a vacuum isn't illegal, various forms of intentionally inflicting emotional distress, discriminating against someone on the basis of race or certain other factors, etc. can be brought and rely on hateful speech as evidence in support of the tort in question. The intended meaning of a communication is certainly relevant in those cases because all such torts require an intent to harm or discriminate and are not merely strict liability offenses.